# enable email on Godaddy when using Zerigo on Heroku hosted app

Tags: domains, dns, email, godaddy, heroku

A little recap of what I have done ... and then my questions Q1, Q2 and Q3

1 - I developed a RoR app that I deployed on Heroku.

```
biowatts.heroku.com
```

2 - I bought a domain name at GoDaddy:

```
biowattsonline.com
```

3 - I am using Zerigo addon as for the DNS

```
heroku addons:add custom_domains
heroku addons:add zerigo_dns:basic
```

4 - Added my domains in Heroku

```
heroku domains:add biowattsonline.com
heroku domains:add www.biowattsonline.com
```

and subdomains

```
heroku domains:add calculator.biowattsonline.com
```

**Q1: Where do we configure the forward to http://biowattsonline.com/biogas_calculator ?**

5 - Configured GoDaddy adding the Zerigo domains

In the Nameservers section

```
a.ns.zerigo.net
b.ns.zerigo.net
c.ns.zerigo.net
d.ns.zerigo.net
e.ns.zerigo.net
```

The GoDaddy DNS section is empty: "Not hosted here"

Ok this works all fine ... http://biowattsonline.com is correctly found

6 - Subdomain forward

I want calculator.biowattsonline.com to be forwarded to biowattsonline.com/biogas_calculator
**Q2: So I created the forward in GoDaddy ... but is that correct?**

7 - GoDaddy email

**Q3: I have one free email account with go GoDaddy, only now that I am using Zerigo I don't know how configure GoDaddy to make it work again?... because it work with the default values**

Any ideason Q1, Q2 and Q3?

Thanks,

Joel

Answer (score 2):

**For Question 1 & Question 2**

To redirect from the subdomain to a URL would require something on the host, I'm almost certain. I've looked all over support a Heroku and can't find anything helpful. I know nothing about Heroku, I'm sorry.

You could accomplish this in Apache with a VirtualHost entry for the subdomain. Also could be done using mod_rewrite (I think).

Heroku support may be able to provide some guidance.

**For Question 3:**

Mail Servers for GoDaddy are:

- smtp.secureserver.net
- mailstore1.secureserver.net

According to [Heroku's FAQ](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/zerigo_dns#managing_mx_and_other_host_records):

> 1. Go to the [My Apps page](https://api.heroku.com/myapps).
> 2. Locate your app, and click on “General Info”.
> 3. Use the add-ons menu on the upper right, and select the Zerigo DNS add-on.
> 4. Once on the add-on page, click the “Configure” for the domain you’d like to manage.
>
> Clicking “Configure” will automatically sign you in to the Zerigo DNS management interface. In there, you have full control to manage your MX Records.